# splitting on whitespace help

Tags: javascript, regex

```
// alerts -> a,b,c,d
// which is correct
window.alert("a b c d".split(/[\u000A-\u000D\u2028\u2029\u0009\u0020\u00A0\uFEFF]+/g));
```

However, this isn't:

```
// alerts -> ,a,b,c,d,
// which is not what we need
// as you can see, there is an extra space
// in the front and end of the array
// it is supposed to alert -> a,b,c,d
// just like our first example

window.alert("   a b c d   ".split(/[\u000A-\u000D\u2028\u2029\u0009\u0020\u00A0\uFEFF]+/g));
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Can you trim the strings first?

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but I think using \s would help cut down on some of those hex values?

Comment: The reason for that is because some browser's \s don't catch all of the whitespace as per the ECMAScript spec. For example, IE doesn't catch the no-break space (0x00A0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always match the inverse of that set instead of splitting.

```
"   a b c d   ".match(/[^\u000A-\u000D\u2028\u2029\u0009\u0020\u00A0\uFEFF]+/g)
```

produces `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`.